# SVG Filter: width 100% height 100% does not cover image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I have a simple SVG Filter. If you click the example below, that filter will appear/disappear:

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');

var url = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/202/200/200.jpg?hmac=eGzhW5P2k0gzjc76Tk5T9lOfvn30h3YHuw5jGnBUY4Y';

image.setAttribute('xlink:href', url);

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var filter = image.getAttribute('filter')
    ? ''
    : 'url(#blur)';
  image.setAttribute('filter', filter);
})
```

```css
image {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <filter id='blur' width='100%' height='100%'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2' result='blur' />
  </filter>
  <image x='0' width='200px' height='200px' xlink:href='' id='svg-image' filter='url(#blur)'  />
</svg>
```

I'd like the filtered image to be the same size as the unfiltered image. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Yikes. Refreshing this same page in recent Chrome shows different behaviors when clicking...

Comment: you need to over-write the default x and y of -10%...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the initial dimension using `x` and `y` attribute as follows.

```
<filter id='blur' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'>
...
```

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');

var url = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/202/200/200.jpg?hmac=eGzhW5P2k0gzjc76Tk5T9lOfvn30h3YHuw5jGnBUY4Y';

image.setAttribute('xlink:href', url);

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var filter = image.getAttribute('filter')
    ? ''
    : 'url(#blur)';
  image.setAttribute('filter', filter);
})
```

```css
image {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <filter id='blur' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2' result='blur' />
  </filter>
  <image x='0' width='200px' height='200px' xlink:href='' id='svg-image' filter='url(#blur)'  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding the filter to have a width of 200px and a height of 200px works

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');

var url = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/202/200/200.jpg?hmac=eGzhW5P2k0gzjc76Tk5T9lOfvn30h3YHuw5jGnBUY4Y';

image.setAttribute('xlink:href', url);

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var filter = image.getAttribute('filter')
    ? ''
    : 'url(#blur)';
  image.setAttribute('filter', filter);
})
```

```css
image {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <filter id='blur' width='200px' height='200px'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2' result='blur' />
  </filter>
  <image x='0' width='200px' height='200px' xlink:href='' id='svg-image' filter='url(#blur)'  />
</svg>
```